# How does Page Life Expectancy correlate with Page Reads/Sec and Page Write/Sec values?

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

I ran two simulations (note: both the simulation are identical) on my server and took the SQL server metrics(especially memory ones).

I observed the page life expectancy for both the simulation which is under the acceptable threshold (acceptable threshold value is above 300), which tells me that during both the run the SQL server's memory is not under stress.

But, when I check the Page Reads/Sec & Page Write/Sec values for both the run, the story changed as their values are beyond the threshold (Page reads/sec & Page Write/sec value should be under 90. Higher values indicate insufficient memory) and which indicates that the SQL server is under memory stress. Any thoughts on this?

Please refer the screenshot attached.
[image]

Comment: off-topic for SO - dba is more appropriate

Comment: Agree, Can I move this conversation to dba?